# Updating existing metadata of my S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to update the existing metadata of my S3 object but in spite of updating it is creating the new one. As per the documentation, it is showing the same way but don't know why it is not able to update it.

```
 k = s3.head_object(Bucket='test-bucket', Key='test.json')
            s3.copy_object(Bucket='test-bucket', Key='test.json', CopySource='test-bucket' + '/' + 'test.json', Metadata={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}, MetadataDirective='REPLACE')
```

Comment: Ah, ok, so just to be clear: the issue is that s3 is adding additional metadata which you don't want? Perhaps update the title reflect the actual issue?

Comment: @Exelian This worked for me

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object(bucketName, uploadedKey)
                          object.copy_from(CopySource={'Bucket': bucketName,'Key': uploadedKey},MetadataDirective="REPLACE",ContentType=value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to update using the `copy_from` method

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object(bucketName, uploadedKey)
object.copy_from(
    CopySource={'Bucket': bucketName,'Key': uploadedKey},
    MetadataDirective="REPLACE",
    ContentType=value
)
```

Comment: If this answer is working for you you can accept your own answer. This will increase visibliity for future users.

Answer (score 1):

S3 metadata is read-only, so updating only metadata of an S3 object is not possible. The only way to update the metadata is to recreate/copy the object. Check the 1st paragraph of the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html)

> You can set object metadata at the time you upload it. After you upload the object, you cannot modify object metadata. The only way to modify object metadata is to make a copy of the object and set the metadata.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even when I am trying to change the bucket with the same process it is still adding an extra metadata